# Macros with multiple parentheses

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

How can I create a macro with multiple parentheses? I don't need variadic number of arguments, I just want to be able to call my macro like.

```
MY_MACRO(arg0, arg1)(arg2)
```

...instead of:

```
MY_MACRO(arg0, arg1, arg2)
```

*Update:*

Let's say I have a macro defined like; `#define MY_MACRO(a, b, c) (a*b/c)` and called like `MY_MACRO(1,2,3)`. How do I transform this macro to being called like `MY_MACRO(1, 2)(3)`

I.e., what I want to do is write my macro as usual, only take the last argument in it's own parenthesis.

Answer (score 4):

```
#define MY_MACRO(a, b) a, b, MY_MACRO1
#define MY_MACRO1(c) c
```

Now doing

```
MY_MACRO(arg0, arg1)(arg2)
```

Will do

```
MY_MACRO(arg0, arg1)(arg2)
a, b, MY_MACRO1 (arg2)
arg0, arg1, MY_MACRO1 (arg2)
arg0, arg1, c
arg0, arg1, arg2
```

Comment: hmm, so if my original macro definition would be `#define MY_MACRO(a,b,c) (a*b/c)`, where would I but the actual code in the second version?

Comment: @Viktor, I don't understand. I thought you want a two argument macro.

Comment: @Viktor, ah I see now. Dunno how to do that :)

Comment: @Viktor of course you can put a `(` at the start of `MY_MACRO` and a closing parenthesis after `MY_MACRO1`. That would answer your direct question. But it appears you want to have a generic solution? I.e forward `MY_MACRO(a, b)(c)` to `MY_MACRO1(a, b, c)`? If so, can you clarify?

Comment: @Johannes: youre perfectly correct, Im looking for a generic solution in which I can write my macro as usual, with difference I take the last argument in its own parenthesis. I'm gonna take some time to experiment with your code thou, havent had the time yet

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MY_MACRO(a, b) (a * b)/ MY_MACRO1
#define MY_MACRO1(c) c

int main() {
    int n = MY_MACRO( 5,6)(3);
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: what if the code was (a+c+b), ie i want to use the c argument at another place than the end?